# Matlab Plotting - Cannot use "MarkerEdgeColor", "MarkerFaceColor", or "MarkerSize" with multiple plots in one plot() command

Tags: matlab, plot

This works:

```
plot(t, pa_iso, '-rs', 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'k', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'r', 'MarkerSize', 5);
plot(t, pc_iso, '-gs', 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'k', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'g', 'MarkerSize', 5);
plot(t, pa_comp, '-bs', 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'k', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'b', 'MarkerSize', 5);
plot(t, pc_comp, '-ms', 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'k', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'm', 'MarkerSize', 5);
```

and this works:

```
plot(t, pa_iso, '-rs', ...
     t, pc_iso, '-gs', ...
     t, pa_comp,'-bs', ...
     t, pc_comp,'-ms');
```

but what I want to do is this:

```
plot(t, pa_iso, '-rs', 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'k', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'r', 'MarkerSize', 5, ...
     t, pc_iso, '-gs', 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'k', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'g', 'MarkerSize', 5, ...
     t, pa_comp, '-bs', 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'k', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'b', 'MarkerSize', 5,...
     t, pc_comp, '-ms', 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'k', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'm', 'MarkerSize', 5);
```

and it throws the error:

```
Error using plot:
    String argument is an unknown option.
```

For some reason, Matlab doesn't like when I concatenate the plots. I would use the first choice, but the problem is that it doesn't plot on the same figure, even if I specify the figure to use. They only plot on separate figures, which is not useful to me. How do I specify different Marker edge colors, face colors, and sizes for each plot in the same plot command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For some reason, Matlab doesn't like when I concatenate the plots.

Yeah. That reason [appears in the documentation](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) (I have added format for emphasis):

> **plot(*_*,Name,Value)** specifies lineseries properties using one or more **Name,Value** pair arguments. Use this option with any of the input argument combinations in the previous syntaxes. **Name,Value** pair settings apply to all the lines plotted. *You cannot specify different **Name,Value** pairs for each line using this syntax*.

You can achieve what you want combining the above syntax with [the following valid syntax for `set`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/set.html):

> **set(H,pn,MxN_pv)** sets n property values on each of m graphics objects, where m = length(H) and n is equal to the number of property names contained in the cell array **pn**. *This allows you to set a given group of properties to different values on each object*.

using this code:

```
h = plot(t, pa_iso,  '-rs', ...
         t, pc_iso,  '-gs', ...
         t, pa_comp, '-bs', ...
         t, pc_comp, '-ms', 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'k', 'MarkerSize', 5);
         %// set linespec as well as common properties. And get a handle
set(h, {'MarkerFaceColor'} , {'r';'g';'b';'m'})
%// Set other, differing properties
```

Comment: Very cool. Good to know! I ended up doing what you said last, and just creating black MarkerEdgeColor and MarkerFaceColor on all 4 plots. Worked perfectly. I set your answer to the "best" answer because it's all encompassing. I could just use "hold" like thewaywewalk mentioned, but this is even more robust I think.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is:

```
plot(t, pa_iso, '-rs', ... stuff ...); hold on
plot(t, pc_iso, '-gs', ... stuff ...); hold on
plot(t, pa_comp, '-bs', ... stuff ...); hold on
plot(t, pc_comp, '-ms', ... stuff ...); hold off
```

`hold on` keep the axes handle for the next plot, so you get everything in the same figure.

Comment: Very helpful. I think I had used hold in another of my projects and it works well for animations as well. I didn't even think to use it here.